# Safari 11.3.1 status bar turned white on white

Tags: html, mobile-safari, meta-tags

I just updated my iOS on iPhone 7 to 11.3.1.  When I add my webapp to front page (standalone mode), the status bar (on the top with connection info) now appears as a solid white bar (white on white).

I've tried:

1. `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`
2. `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">`
3. `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">`
4. `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white">`
5. Removing meta tag completely.

All to no avail.  I don't really care what color it is, but the white bar looks dumb. Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Can't figure it out!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to add `viewport-fit=cover` to your viewport meta tag content.

Apparently, as of recently, the status bar will not overlap the content by default. This setting will override that. So your viewport meta tag might look something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Just a note for others stumbling around, the `viewport-fit=cover` is related to [notch support](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/). If you rely on something like `body { height: 100%; }`, setting `viewport-fit=cover` will not longer cover the whole page (you need to do `height: calc(100% + env(safe-area-inset-top) + env(safe-area-inset-bottom));`).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/PWA/comments/pynzs0/comment/hhkzkeq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on Reddit. Using...

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
```

...was the ONLY way I got a black status bar with white text. iOS 15.1, iPhone 11 Pro.